# Gmail Contextual Gadget API: Is there a way to access the RFC 822 Message ID?

Tags: gmail-contextual-gadgets

is there a way to access the RFC 822 Message ID from within a Contextual Gadget?
According to https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets?hl=de#supported_scopes only the Google Message ID can be accessed.

However, I don't understand this restriction, as the Google Message ID is also accessible...

Best regards,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

No not directly, but you can if you use some java there is a api which can solve your problem.

you can find it here

https://code.google.com/p/java-gmail-imap/

MY CODE:

```
IMAPFolder folder = (IMAPFolder) store.getFolder("[Gmail]/All Mail");

        FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
        fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
        fp.add(IMAPFolder.FetchProfileItem.X_GM_THRID);
        fp.add(IMAPFolder.FetchProfileItem.X_GM_MSGID);


        if (folder != null) {
            folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            folder.fetch(folder.getMessages(), fp);

            GmailMessageIDTerm messageID_term = new GmailMessageIDTerm(Long.parseLong(msgId, 16)+"");
            com.google.code.javax.mail.Message[] messageID_Meassages = folder.search(messageID_term);


            if(messageID_Meassages.length > 0){

                IMAPMessage main_Meassage = (IMAPMessage)messageID_Meassages[0];
                GmailThreadIDTerm thread_term = new GmailThreadIDTerm(main_Meassage.getGoogleMessageId() + "");
                com.google.code.javax.mail.Message[] thread_Messages = folder.search(thread_term);


                for(com.google.code.javax.mail.Message m: thread_Messages){
                    IMAPMessage imapMessage = (IMAPMessage)m;
                    // here is your every message of current thread 

                }

            }
        }
```